# EFT CTP5 Disable Identity column on insert

Tags: entity-framework-ctp5

I have an existing database that I would like to migrate to EF CTP5.  The problem I have is that when I insert the existing data I need it to move retaining the current identity primary key for the other foreign key constraints.

I would like to migrate this using EF CTP5 code so I dont have to write lots of SQL or even contain it within an SSIS Package.

I have attempted to use the sql syntax:

SET IDENTITY_INSERT tableName ON

SET IDENTITY_INSERT tableName OFF

However, when DbContext.SaveChanges() is called the above syntax is happening in a different connection and the identity column is controlled by the EF CTP5 framework, even when specifying the ID.

Is there a way of disabling, or removing the identity convention to an object similar to the following, but on the fly rather than when the database is instantiated:

```
public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<StoreGeneratedIdentityKeyConvention>();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can add the Identity setting on a field like so:

In your OnModelCreating in your DbContext class:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ClassNameOfYourPOCO>().Property(p => p.IDFIELDNAME)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
```

You can remove it like so:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ClassNameOfYourPOCO>().Property(p => p.IDFIELDNAME)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
    }
```